# Rails - Easy way to display all fields in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

OK I'm sure I'm missing something here, but please forgive me I'm new to Rails.

Is there some way in Rails to display all the fields for an object rather than specifying each?

In my show.html template rather than going

```
<p>Name: <%=h @user.full_name %></p>
<p>Email: <%=h @user.email %></p>
```

I just want a oneliner to do this without having to type out each of the 15 or so fields I have. 
Its an admin page so its fine if all the fields are shown (id, created_at, etc.)
If this was PHP it would take me about 5 secs using foreach, but I've googled (on the wrong things obviously) for an hour with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Something like

```
<% for attribute in @user.attributes.keys %>
  <p><%= attribute.humanize %> <%= @user.attributes[attribute].to_s %></p>
<% end %>
```

could do the trick.

Matt

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted too! 
.humanize huh! I think I need that for my kids sometimes

Comment: love it! I ended up using:
`<% for attribute in ['name', 'age', 'etc'] %>`
To only show the fields I want to show.

Comment: I googled for an hour before I found this. So grateful

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you want to display all attributes of a row from database table which is defined as ActiveRecord model. You can use class method *column_names* (every ActiveRecord model has it), which returns names of table columns in an array.

```
<%= User.column_names.collect { |col_name| "#{col_name.capitalize}: <p>#{@user[col_name]}</p>" }.join("\n") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= debug @user %>
```

simple way to show the object... that is what I usually use anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.attributes.each{|key, value| puts "#{key} : #{value}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet I used to blacklist some attributes I didn't want to show...

**controller (user_controller.rb)**

```
def show

    keys_blacklist = %W(user_id name) #these are the fields to hide
    @user_showlist = @user.attributes.except(*keys_blacklist)

end
```

**view (show.html.erb):**

```
<!-- language: ruby --><% for attribute in @user_showlist.keys %> 

  <b><%= attribute.humanize %></b>
  <%= @user.attributes[attribute].to_s %>
<!-- language: ruby --><% end %>
```

---

You can also use instead:

```
@user_showlist = @user.attributes.slice(*keys_whitelist)
```

in order to display a whilelist of properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using haml and want to loop through the attributes on for example a user object in a view:

```
- for attribute in @user.attributes.keys
  %p
    = attribute.humanize
    = @user.attributes[attribute].to_s
```